# Select number of comma delimited list items

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column that has comma seperated values and I need to select all rows that have 13 commas.  They seperate numbers so I don't need to worry about any strings that contain commas.  How would I do this?

Comment: You should not ever store comma separated values in a field. This indicates that what you need is a related table. Then you could do a simple count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count a string with 14 commas as having 13 commas, then this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'
```

`%` matches any string (including zero length).

Comment: This will give an incorrect result for any record that have more than 13 commas. This is dangerous code and should not be the accepted answer or used in an application.

Comment: @HLGEM a) I gave a warning about matching against more than 13 commas; b) The string "aaa" does have 2 a's (i.e. question wasn't explicit, hence my answer with warning; the fact that OP accepted it suggests this is not a problem) c) Saying it is dangerous without saying why doesn't help much.

Comment: It's dangerous because it will not give the expected result in all cases and people may not see the warning or correctly understand it. ajreal's solution is better and the OP needs to know that he did not choose the best solution for his problem.

Comment: @HLGEM You're assuming @arjeal's solution is what OP wants. What if he *wants* to match strings with 42 commas? I gave a clear warning of what mine does and OP accepted it. I'd say that's enough to warrant this being fully correct, until OP says otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

alternative to like (I do not like the `like`, and the above will fail if contains 14 commas or more)

```
select * from table
where length(replace(your_column, ',', ''))=length(your_column)-13;
```

for better utilize the index, you should seek to normalize your table

Comment: +1 for that. Surely you wanted to add to *never* introduce such a statement in a production environment?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you could also use regular expressions.

However, a better question might be why you have a single column with comma-separated values instead of multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can do:

```
select col from table where length(regexp_replace(col, '[^,]', '', 'g')) = 13;
```